# Aeron - Issues with Multicast across Switches

Tags: java, multicast, aeron, reliable-multicast

I am trying to run a Basic Publisher/Subscriber pair on the same Multicast/Port. It works perfectly when the hosts are connected to the same Switch, but not if the subscriber is on a different Switch.

**Publisher**

```
java '-Daeron.sample.channel=aeron:udp?endpoint=224.0.1.1:40123|interface=192.168.1.0/24' -Daeron.sample.embeddedMediaDriver=true -cp ./lib/aeron-all-1.29.0.jar io.aeron.samples.BasicPublisher
```

**Subscriber**

```
java '-Daeron.sample.channel=aeron:udp?endpoint=224.0.1.1:40123|interface=192.168.9.0/24' -Daeron.sample.embeddedMediaDriver=true -cp ./lib/aeron-all-1.29.0.jar io.aeron.samples.BasicSubscriber
```

Since the hosts has multiple interfaces, I have explicitly tried to bind the Publisher/Subscriber to a specific interface, by defining the interface parameter as a part of the Channel Configuration.

Mulit-cast routes between the 2 boxes has been verified using `iperf`

Comment: Have you tried setting the TTL for the multicast traffic: `aeron.socket.multicast.ttl` (https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/wiki/Configuration-Options)

Comment: With `iperf `have you tested the return direction on the even numbered address for the control messages? https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/wiki/Transport-Protocol-Specification#multicast-mode-of-operation

Comment: Both the Data and the Control (224.0.1.2 ) multicast working bi-directional and validated with iperf. Thank you @MartinThompson

Comment: Looks like setting the ttl works - Thank you @MichaelBarker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make it work with adding a **ttl** config option.

**Publisher**

```
java '-Daeron.sample.channel=aeron:udp?endpoint=224.0.1.1:40123|interface=192.168.1.0/24|ttl=16' -Daeron.sample.embeddedMediaDriver=true -cp ./lib/aeron-all-1.29.0.jar io.aeron.samples.BasicPublisher
```

**Subscriber**

```
java '-Daeron.sample.channel=aeron:udp?endpoint=224.0.1.1:40123|interface=192.168.9.0/24|ttl=16' -Daeron.sample.embeddedMediaDriver=true -cp ./lib/aeron-all-1.29.0.jar io.aeron.samples.BasicSubscriber
```